# Store contents of help() in a variable: Python

Tags: python, pydoc

When we use the help() function it just displays the text and I can't store it in a variable...

```
h = help ( 'eval' ) # Doesn't work
```

So what do I do? And if I need to use PyDoc, how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way it to use the `__doc__` attribute as @Thomas said

If you want the exact output as what `help(something)` gives, then use

```py
import contextlib
import io

out_io = io.StringIO()

with contextlib.redirect_stdout(out_io):
    help(eval)

out_io.seek(0)
# out has what you're looking for
out = out_io.read()
```

### Explanation:

`contextlib.redirect_stdout` temporarily patches sys.stdout to any file like object you pass it

We pass in a `StringIO` object as the file-like object and it gets the *printed* value written to it

Then finally the `StringIO` object is seeked back to the start and read from

Answer (score 2):

The `__doc__` attribute is what you're looking for:

```
>>> h = eval.__doc__
>>> h
'Evaluate the given source in the context of globals and locals.\n\nThe source may be a string representing a Python expression\nor a code object as returned by compile().\nThe globals must be a dictionary and locals can be any mapping,\ndefaulting to the current globals and locals.\nIf only globals is given, locals defaults to it.'
```

Comment: The output is not the same as what `help('eval')` gives.